# How do you get top recent azure devops pipelines using Rest api?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to fetch azure devops piplelines run based on some query using Rest API.

Query : 1:first 100 recent pipelines
2: Date range

Document refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

But Using this I cant get top 50 run.

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you looking for the runs for a specific pipeline, or all recent runs for all pipelines?

Comment: All pipelines in recent run